# Web Scraping Div Class Not Found

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the information on chambers.com, more specifically in this example https://chambers.com/law-firm/allen-overy-llp-global-2:7. The information I want is the different departments and the bands that are under the "UK" section on the "Ranked Department" tab. Image of the section below: [image]

The problem I'm currently having is with beautiful soup's `find_all`, and I assume the parser. I want to find all `<div class="mb-3">` The code I have so far is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url_to_scrape = 'https://chambers.com/law-firm/allen-overy-llp-global-2:7'

plain_html_text = requests.get(url_to_scrape)

soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_html_text.content, "lxml")

search = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "mb-3"})

print(search)
```

and nothing is returned in the list. I have taken the class from the HTML using the inspector on my browser.

I have tried adding the HTML directly into the pyhton file, I have also tried using `html.parser` but still nothing returned.

Any help would be much appreciaated, even if it a suggestion of where to look.

Comment: One of the biggest issues in web scraping is client-side rendering. Do you know for sure that there isn't some javascript loading this information after the document is loaded in the web browser? You may need to use a library like Selenium. See article [here](https://sadesmith.com/2018/06/15/blog/scraping-client-side-rendered-data-with-python-and-selenium) for example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Caleb. I dont know if there is javascript loading this information, is there a way to work this out? I will have a look at the article you have attached. Thanks agian.

Comment: I would look into "plain_html_text.content" and build the search query based on what is there.

Comment: Okay, they're using Angular, which is usually client-side. I also used `curl` to request the page, and the data you're looking for isn't returned, so you will need to use some kind of tool that can web scrape client-side rendered websites. Hopefully that link helps, good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the source of the page, you will find there is no such an element in this page. Scrape the API:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.chambers.com/api/organisations/7/ranked-departments?publicationTypeGroupId=2'
response = requests.get(url).json()
for location in response['locations']:
    if location['description'] == 'UK':
        for info in location['rankedEntities']:
            print(info["displayName"], info['rankings'][0]['rankingDescription'], sep="\n", end="\n\n")
```

Print:

```
Banking & Finance: Borrowers
Band 1

Banking & Finance: Lenders
Band 1

Banking & Finance: Sponsors
Band 2

Capital Markets: Debt
Band 1

Capital Markets: Derivatives
Band 1

Capital Markets: Equity
Band 1

Capital Markets: Securitisation
Band 1

Capital Markets: Structured Finance
Band 1

Competition Law
Band 2

Corporate M&A (International & Cross-Border)
Band 1

Dispute Resolution: International Arbitration
Band 2

Dispute Resolution: Litigation
Band 1

Disputes (International & Cross-Border)
Band 1

Employment
Band 2

Energy & Natural Resources: Oil & Gas
Band 1

Energy & Natural Resources: Power
Band 1

Energy & Natural Resources: Renewables & Alternative Energy
Band 1

Energy Sector (International & Cross-Border)
Band 1

Finance & Capital Markets (International & Cross-Border)
Band 1

Insurance: Mainly Policyholders
Band 1

Intellectual Property
Band 2

Intellectual Property: Patent Litigation
Band 1

Investigations & Enforcement (International & Cross-Border)
Band 2

Investment Funds & Asset Management (International & Cross-Border)
Band 2

Life Sciences & Pharmaceutical Sector (International & Cross-Border)
Band 2

Projects
Band 1

Restructuring/Insolvency
Band 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `soup.find_all("div", {"class": "mb-3"})` use

```py
soup.find_all("div", class_="mb-3"})
```

Comment: Actually, this makes no difference. You can check on your own -- the search is still an empty list.

Comment: Ok, I'll try on my system.